# Meaning of 'Fiddle' in it services

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

There are a lot of various services named 'fiddle' in IT. (js fiddle, sql fiddle etc).

What does it mean and where did come from?

I guess that it's something like 'play with' (like violin or at the playground or in the sandbox), is it right?

And 'to fiddle' equals 'to play', 'to test' and so on, and 'the fiddle' is 'a script', 'some piece of code' etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a synonym of '[to tinker](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tinker)':

> to work in the manner of a tinker; especially :  to repair, adjust, or work with something in an unskilled or experimental manner

Code at these places is often not formally written, more thrown together, and fiddled with.